# Changing font size according to locale change in Spring 3

Tags: spring-mvc, locale, font-size

I used three language in my spring application. But when I change language then needed to change font size since the words breaks in its position. Is it possible to change fontsize when the locale change in spring mvc 3?

```
                              <li>
                                <a href="#invitation-part" id="invitation-sent" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <spring:message code="label.ghViewUserTabInvitationsSent" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#inbox-part" id="inbox" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <spring:message code="label.ghViewUserTabInbox" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
```

English: a)label.ghViewUserTabInvitationsSent = Sent invitations

```
     b)label.ghViewUserTabInbox = Inbox
```

Spnaish: a)label.ghViewUserTabInvitationsSent = Invitaciones Enviadas

```
     b)label.ghViewUserTabInbox = Bandeja de Entrada
```

Comment: What about changing themes/css based on locale.

Comment: Thanks for comment. But what is the procedure ? can you give me any example please.